# Apache 2.4 Redundant LDAP Authentication

Tags: authentication, apache-2.4, httpd, http-basic-authentication, mod-auth-ldap

I'm trying to provide a redundant LDAP authentication to my webserver.

```
ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-one>
   AuthLDAPBindDN "search@domain"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "pass"
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://###.###.###.###/dc=domain,dc=local?sAMAccountName?sub" NONE
</AuthnProviderAlias>
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-two>
   AuthLDAPBindDN "search@domain"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "pass"
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://###.###.###.###/dc=domain,dc=local?sAMAccountName?sub" NONE
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
   Order deny,allow 
   Allow from all
   AuthBasicProvider ldap-one ldap-two
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authentication" 
   Require valid-user
</Directory>

Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   AuthBasicProvider ldap-one ldap-two
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authentication"
   Require valid-user
</Directory>`
```

It works! However, the whole point of this is that when ldap-one is offline for whatever reason, I can still login. So, I change the IP address of ldap-one to another ip address that doesn't go anywhere, and reload.

Now I get an "Internal Server Error" when I try to log in. If I switch the order in AuthBasicProvider to ldap-two ldap-one then it does work.

So it looks like it's only checking the first entry for AuthBasicProvider.

This is the document/example I've been following: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html

Info:

```
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Many thanks,

Ollie

Comment: take a look http://serverfault.com/questions/402260/multiple-ldap-servers-with-mod-authn-alias-failover-not-working-when-the-first

Comment: Thanks - thought I'd looked everywhere but didn't see that post. I'd already tried that method, but with ldap://ipaddress:389 ldap://ipaddress:389, instead of ldap://ipaddress:389 ipaddress:389/dc=... obviously didn't read the docs properly!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple LDAP servers with mod\_authn\_alias: failover not working when the first LDAP is down?](https://serverfault.com/questions/402260/multiple-ldap-servers-with-mod-authn-alias-failover-not-working-when-the-first)